# Making containers side by side in desktop and mobile version Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple project I am working but I am stuck on one part. I have created 2 dropdown menus. I want them to appear side by side when I am on a desktop, which is what its doing right now. However, I am supposed to make it appear side by side when I get to a mobile version and thats where I am getting stuck on. I have put the relevant section of my code below(you guys can ignore the angular stuff, I am just stuck on the layout right now). Please help. Thank you

```
<div class="card"> 
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card-heading">Visit/Call Time Spent<sup>*</sup></div>
   <ul class="card-detail ">
    <li>
     <select  class="sf1select"   
              id="reportFocusSelect"
              ng-model="callReport.Duration_of_Visit_Call_mins__c" 
              ng-change="changeDiscussionPointPicklist()"
              ng-options="t.name for t in timeoptions" ng-required="true"/>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="card-heading">Transit to Agency<sup>*</sup></div>
    <ul class="card-detail ">
     <li>
      <select  class="sf1select"   
                id="reportFocusSelect"
                ng-model="callReport.Transit_to_Agency__c" 
                ng-change="changeDiscussionPointPicklist()"
                ng-options="t.name for t in transitoptions" ng-required="true"/>
     </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div class="col-xs-6">` instead of `<div class="col-md-6">`.

col-md-x means "x columns on screen sizes *medium* or larger", mobile screens are smaller than medium and you did not specify how the layout should look there, therefore it defaults to 12 columns. using col-xs-6 makes it 6 columns on *extra small* screens and larger.

Also keep in mind, that "col" classes might not work correctly if not included in a "row", so I recommend adding a row to your card.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```